# Are multiple unrelated links to my site from a single domain damaging?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, pagerank

In GWT I can see a site which has 283 links to a single page on my site. Their content is completely irrelevant to my site (see image below).

I can't even find where the actual link is on their pages, which makes me super suspicious.

Are all these links to my page damaging to SEO and ranking?

How would I block a domain like this from linking to my site?
[image]

Answer (score 5):

A single site linking to yours is unlikely to trigger any of Google's spam alerts for your domain.   Google penalizes a site when it sees a pattern of spammy links from many domains.   Your site will also have plenty of legitimate, non-spammy inbound links.  Those good links will innoculate your site against ill effects from links from few bad sites.

My own sites tyically get links like this and I don't worry about it.   One time I had a network of pornography sites all linking to me because they were using one of my widgets.   Nothing bad ever came of it.  I often see mass links from scaper sites and badly implemented directory sites pointing to my sites.   Because all sites get some of these, a few of them for your own site is nothing to worry about.

Google does have a [disavow links tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/disavow-links-main) in Webmaster Tools.  This tool can be used to tell Google about spammy links to your site.   When you use this tool you are telling Google that it should ignore all the spammy links you identify.  [Here is the help document](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2648487?hl=en) about the tool.   Google has said, however, that you **should not use the disavow links tool** unless you see evidence that spammy links have caused a penalty or hurt your rankings.  If you do use it, it can really hurt your site because Google won't pass any link juice across links that you have disavowed.

Comment: Perfectly said! I would like to reiterate the fact that low quality links are expected. Google knows what sites make low quality links and does not penalize the target site for these links. Where links hurt you are where a deliberate pattern of manipulative links are established. This is fairly easy to establish through pattern recognition making otherwise low quality links easier to understand. It is not a problem. I would also say that Disavow Link is absolutely the last step only when there is a clear problem and not a suspected problem. Even these spam links have some accumulative value.

Answer (score 2):

Yes links like this can potently be hurting your site, and that's why Google introduced the [disavow fearure](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/disavow-links-main).

The disavow feature lets you specify a list of website pages, or entire domains that you know are linking to you but want to tell Google to discount them from your link profile that Google uses in their algorithms.

You can find some more info on using the disavow here on [Pro Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=disavow) and on [Google's site](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2648487?hl=en).

Make sure you know what you are doing and with it though as it is a very powerful feature and if you disavow the wrong links you could severely harm your websites ranking.

Answer (score 2):

John Mueller from Google said in its wbemaster hangouts videos that links from irrelevant but non-spammy websites have no negative impact on target sites. No need to disavow them.

Google also detect spammy sites and neutralize their links automatically (they are treated as nofollow). Besides, if a website linking to you is manually penalized by Google, it won't impact your site unless you participate in a link scheme or in black hat activities with it.

If you still have doubt, you can disavow suspicious sites. Their links will be progressively treated as nofollow.